# React Native fetch only returns on second or third attempt

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, async.js, asyncstorage

I have a fetch that uses a parameter that is saved locally with AsyncStorage. But my fetch only returns data on second or third attempt, so when I try to map the data on my render it says it cannot map undefined data.

Here is my AsyncStorage and fetch code:

```
  componentWillMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then((codigo)=>{
      this.setState({value: JSON.parse(codigo)});
      this.getData()
    })
  }


  getData(){
    fetch(`URL/portalacv_ws.asmx/GetDetalhesViatura?CarID=${this.state.value}`)
    .then((response) => { return response.json()})
    .then(res => {
       this.setState({data: res})
    })
  }
```

this is what I get on console:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is both method are `async`. In your case you should call to `getData` as a callback after getting the item.

### Explanation with your code:

```js
componentWillMount(){
  AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then((codigo)=>{
    //This code runs async, so when you call getData, value has not been changed yet (Or at least you cannot be sure).
    this.setState({value: JSON.parse(codigo)});
    //Printing here this.state.value will help you to understand
    this.getData()
  })
}

getData(){
  fetch(`URL/portalacv_ws.asmx/GetDetalhesViatura?CarID=${this.state.value}`)
  .then((response) => { return response.json()})
  .then(res => {
     this.setState({data: res})
  })
}
```

### How to solve it?:

```js
componentWillMount(){
  AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then((codigo)=>{
    this.setState({value: JSON.parse(codigo)}, () => {
        //Here you are pretty sure that the setState has already done.
        this.getData()
    });
  })
}

getData(){
  fetch(`URL/portalacv_ws.asmx/GetDetalhesViatura?CarID=${this.state.value}`)
  .then((response) => { return response.json()})
  .then(res => {
     this.setState({data: res})
  })
}
```

### EDITED:

After taking a look at the whole component, the conclusion is that render method is being executed once before setState and once after, that is why you have the first time undefined, and the second time the value you are expecting.

So one possible way in order to solve this situation, is by flaging the action of fetching data and render after the fetch is finished. More or less, the idea would be:

```js
export default class Favoritos extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
      data: null,
      fetching: false
    };

    //Binding is not needed, but...
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({ fetching: true }, () => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then((codigo)=>{
        this.setState({value: JSON.parse(codigo)}, () => {
          this.getData()
            .then((data) => {
              this.setState({
                data: data,
                fetching: false
              })
            })
        });
      })
    });
  }


  getData(){
    return fetch(`URL/portalacv_ws.asmx/GetDetalhesViatura?CarID=${this.state.value}`)
             .then((response) => { return response.json()})
  }

  onPress(){
    this.setState({ fetching: true }, () => {
      this.getData()
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({
            data: data,
            fetching: false
          })
        })
    });
  }   

  render() {
    if(this.state.fethcing){
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
          Fetching data...
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
          <ScrollView>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress}>
              ...
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <Text>
              {this.state.value}
            </Text>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

In the code above, I've left only the code that makes sense to question, the original one has much more code.

Comment: thanks for the answer! unfortunately it didn't work. Printing `this.state.value`does in fact print the number correctly. But when it tries to fetch the data it tries 2 or 3 times.

Comment: Ok, but then we have some more complex situation. How many times is being executed `componentWillMount`? What is the outcome of the `AsyncStorage.getItem`? It should not try more than just once, so if it is being executed more than one time, perhaps we have some kind of looping somewhere. if you add a console.log at the beggining of the `componentWillMount`, how many times do see that log?

Comment: `componentWillMount` is executing only 1 time, and the `AsyncStorage` is returning a car id, in this case it's returning this number `437615`.

Comment: So, what's the value you see just before the `fetch`?

Comment: Before the fetch im getting `undefined`, like on the print screen I shared. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Did you try the way I've proposed? I mean, calling `getData` in the callback passed to `setState`.

Comment: yep, and still can't fetch on first try. Spent hours on this, can't really see where is the error.

Comment: Would you mind to share the whole component please? Let's see if there is something else trying to execute `getData`

Comment: I think your problem is that render is being executed twice: one immediately componentWillMount and the next one after the state is set. I think you should flag the render to wait until the componentWillMount finishes.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Im accepting the answer, you can edit it with your comment if you want.

Comment: I will update the answer, BTW, you should initialize your state in the contructor, in this example, data and value should be initializaed. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't know that, any reason why I should initialize it?

Comment: It will avoid unexpected behaviors, but as a best practice, you might want to have defined the whole state.